# Pause javascript raphael animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

I had created an animation with raphael script.
The animation works fine, but I want to have a function that pause it and start it in the same place that it's pause
I found this script on raphaels homepage, but dont really know how to implement it.

```
    elproto.stop = function (anim) {
        for (var i = 0; i < animationElements.length; i++) if (animationElements[i].el.id == this.id && (!anim || animationElements[i].anim == anim)) {
            if (eve("anim.stop." + this.id, this, animationElements[i].anim) !== false) {
                animationElements.splice(i--, 1);
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
```

I know ofcourse that i should modify the string, but since In a beginner I get stuck already on
`elproto.stop` ..

This is my function that starts my animation

```
function moveRect1()
{

if( xEnd == 150 )
xEnd = 50;
else
xEnd = 150;


rect1.animate( {x: xEnd},                   
1000,                           
"Sine",                     
function (){ moveRect1(); } 
            );
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Well. I figured it out at last.

Just used this funtion

function stopRect1() {
rect1.pause();

    };